# Apache Drill: Convert JSON as String to JSON object to retrieve each element

Tags: apache-drill

I have the below string in a column in `hive table` which i am trying to query using `apache drill`:

> {"cdrreasun":"52","cdxscarc":"20150407161405","cdrend":"20150407155201","cdrdnrar.1un":"24321.70","servlnqlp":"54.201.25.50","men":"42403","xa:lnqruup":"3","cemcau":"120","accuuncl":"21","cdrc:
>   5","volcuca":"1.7"}

Want to **retrieve all values for key** cdrreasun using **apache drill SQL**.

Can't use FLATTEN on the column as it says `Flatten does not work with inputs of non-list types.`

Can't use KVGEN as well as it works only with MAP datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, hope it will be helpful for others.

We have to do it in 3 steps if the datatype is of type MAP:

> KVGEN() -> FLATTEN() -> convert_from()

If it's of type `STRING` then `KVGEN()` function is not needed.

```
SELECT ratinggrouplist
    ,t3.cdrlist3.cdrreason AS cdrreason
    ,t3.cdrlist3.cdrstart AS cdrstart
    ,t3.cdrlist3.cdrend AS cdrend
    ,t3.cdrlist3.cdrduration AS cdrduration
FROM (
    SELECT ratinggrouplist, convert_from(t2.cdrlist2.`element`, 'JSON') AS cdrlist3
    FROM (
        SELECT ratinggrouplist ,flatten(t1.cdrlist1.`value`) AS cdrlist2
        FROM (
            SELECT ratinggrouplist, kvgen(cdrlist) AS cdrlist1
            FROM dfs.tmp.SOME_TABLE
            ) AS t1
        ) AS t2
    ) AS t3;
```

Answer (score 3):

Drill has function convert_fromJSON which allows converting from String to JSON object. For more details about this function and examples of usage please see https://drill.apache.org/docs/data-type-conversion/#convert_to-and-convert_from

For the example you specified, you can run

```
convert_fromJSON(colWithJsonText)['cdrreasun']
```